# Why the flow of execution of the following cases was different?

Tags: java, c#, oop, object

Can someone please elaborate me in detail the following scenario, it would be more convenient if the explanation includes the memory allocation and its reference for the three cases :

1. How is the flow executed in the three cases ?
2. Why the flow differ in the three cases ?
3. Though there is a circular dependency between the two classes why the case 1 alone gets executed where as the remaining cases were failed ?

**CASE ONE**

```
namespace CircularDependency_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            Console.WriteLine("executed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public static A a = new A();

        public B()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Creating B");
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public static B  b = new B();

        public A()
        {          
            Console.WriteLine("Creating A");
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Creating A
Creating B
Creating A
executed
```

**CASE TWO**

```
namespace CircularDependency_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            Console.WriteLine("executed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public static A a;

        public B()
        {
            a = new A();
            Console.WriteLine("Creating B");
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public static B b;

        public A()
        {      
             b = new B();
            Console.WriteLine("Creating A");
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

**CASE THREE**

```
namespace CircularDependency_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            Console.WriteLine("executed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public A a;

        public B()
        {
            a = new A();
            Console.WriteLine("Creating B");
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public B b;

        public A()
        {      
             b = new B();
            Console.WriteLine("Creating A");
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

Comment: Why did you include the `java` label ?

Comment: @svasa i think the question is more about OOPS rather than language oriented

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @RealSkeptic this is not a homework and im not a student too. I'm more curious to know how/why the things happen to that way.
Also I know that for case 1: ObjectA is created from classB and ObjectB is created from classA and ObjectA is created from main method. But the question is why alone in the first case?

Comment: did you try executing your test cases using a debugger?  (for the ones that throw an exception, you should be able to examine the top of the stack to see what's happening).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Versatile, you are close, but not right. The reason why the first case executes and two other cases fail, is not just because the objects are created inside the constructor or inside the class (outside of the constructor). To prove this, try making the `a` and `b` fields not static in the `B` and `A` classes (Case one), respectively; and you will see that it will fail, even though the objects are created outside of the constructor.

Case 2 and 3 fail because of the reasons explained by @Versatile. 
Case 1 executes because of `static` members. 
Let's examine the flow:

In the `Main` method the line `A a = new A()` begins creating the `a` object. In this process, an object of class `B` will be created because of the line `public static B b = new B()` - this very line will start creating another object of the class `A` because of the line `public static A a = new A()` in the body of class `B`. Now, here comes the magic (that doesn't fire a circular dependency). This line, `public static A a = new A()` will start creating another object of class `A`, while creating this object it won't create another object of class `B` because it is a static member of `A`, and it was already created. As we know, static members of a class are shared among all instances of the class. Therefore, it won't trigger the creation of another object of class `B`. In total, we end up with three instances of the classes in the order : `A`, `B`, `A`.

**UPDATE**

It is interesting to observe, in the first case, what happens if we initialize the static member inside the constructor. Even though, the `A` and `B` classes declare static members, the execution will fail due to circular dependency. This is because the static members are not initialized before the constructor is executed.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that. I assumed that the usage of static was evident that the object will be created only once and moreover as it was being assigned new memory at that line hence it does not go into recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

1.How is the flow executed in the three cases ?
First the static void Main() gets called and then the constructor of object A is called because of code line `A a = new A();`

2.Why the flow differ in the three cases ?

3.Though there is a circular dependency between the two classes why the case 1 alone gets executed where as the remaining cases were failed ?

Both the above scenarios are observed for the same reason. If you look closely, you assign memory as follows.
Case1 in the class and not the constructor. i.e.

```
public class A
{
    public static B  b = new B();
}
```

Moreover the object is static so it will be created only once and as this is created once the memory which is assigned in the same line gets executed only once.

Case 2 and Case 3: Memory to Objects A and B is assigned in the constructor  i.e. in constructor of A the memory is assigned to B and in constructor of B memory is assigned to A, which results in calling the respective class constructors again and again until it throws an exception.